# Where to set up php file to connect to wordpress database?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

My question involves more of how/where to set the file up.  I have a database from a plugin (woocommerce) used in wordpress, and I want a php file to be able to gather the newly added rows from the database and add it into another database (in multiple tables) which is stored in phpmyadmin.

I don't know where to begin, can this file be in the same folder as the plugin contents?  How can I check my code along the way?  If there are errors, where will error messages display?

I assume I will be connecting to the wordpress database, getting the rows, connecting to the phpmyadmin database, and inserting the rows into it.  The plugin and wordpress files are on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with Cron job. Cron job will repeat that file after specified time and will update your database values.

Comment: Adding a link to the documentation will make your Answer substantively better ;)

Comment: Okay, but that's just to schedule the file to run, I still don't know where this file should go, or how to even check that its working. Any ideas?